Material Outline Input - Creating the Notch in Angular
Hi I am trying to implement a custom material outline input that includes a notch where the label is floating.
I know there is an existing component for Angular Material but I need to have my own special customisation therefore building my own.
I have gotten this far in creating the floating but having trouble creating the actual notch. I have seen solutions where its just a white background behind the label but that wont work in mine as input background is a different colour.
Any help/strategies best to do this would be great. I am ok with using JS what ever will work as long as it be consistent across multiple browsers is the main thing. Many thanks in advance.
Here is my stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5nxde-xdq3qy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

expected:

Code:
     HTML 
<div class="material-textfield">
      <input placeholder=" " type="text" value="test" />
      <label class="label-container">Label</label>
    </div>

CSS
    .material-textfield {
  position: relative;
}

.label-container {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  transform-origin: left top;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
  color: gray;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;

  background-color: beige;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: #6200ee;
}
input:focus + .label-container {
  color: #6200ee;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
  border-color: #6200ee; /* Color on focus */
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label-container {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
  border-color: #6200ee; /* Color when input is not empty */
}


I won't be able to produce a code answer tonight but I may be able to help with some insights, the outlined mat form field uses three html element to achieve this notched outline, they all have dedicated css classes named mdc-notched-outline__leading mdc-notched-outline__notch and mdc-notched-outline__trailing.
The border is basically divided in three and the border top of the middle element is removed when the input is focused.

Thanks for replying that would be awesome!! I have scoured the internet but lot of css is broken. Interesting to understand as still don’t know how you can divide each border.

I've tried to reproduce the notched outline behaviour with the minimal amount of code, I've used the technique that I've described in my previous comment :
The notched border is made out of three html elements, they are contained in an absolute flex div palced behind the actual input,
The first name named trailing lives in a fixed padding added before the input.
The second element named notch contains the label so that the notch is the size of the label.
The last element named trailing take the remaining space after the label.
And here's the implementation :


.form-field {
  --input-pading: 16px;
  --border: solid 1px black;
  --border-radius: 4px;

  padding-left: var(--input-pading);

  min-width: 0;
  max-height: 56px;
  max-width: 248px;

  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-field:focus-within {
  --border: solid 2px black;
}

.notched-outline {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.notched-outline .leading {
  border-radius: var(--border-radius) 0 0 var(--border-radius);
  border-left: var(--border);
  border-top: var(--border);
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  width: var(--input-pading);
}

.notched-outline .notch {
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}
.notched-outline .notch .label {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.notched-outline .trailing {
  border-radius: 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) 0;
  border-right: var(--border);
  border-top: var(--border);
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  width: 100%;
}

.form-field-infix {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: var(--input-pading);
  padding-top: var(--input-pading);
}

.form-field-infix input {
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="notched-outline">
    <div class="leading"></div>
    <div class="notch">
      <div class="label">Label</div>
    </div>
    <div class="trailing"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-infix">
    <input placeholder="test" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>




wow thanks for taking the time to doing this.  Ive implemented in below stack and is perfect my needs (label floating from input to top animation is not in this solution but I dont need it). I am very surprised this was all done without JS. Very well done thanks again! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5nxde-rg8xbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.css

Yeah the floating label changing position would definitely require some JS, glad I could help !

Thanks one thing I noticed the label size is fixed. If there is longer text it wraps. Any idea how to have it expand to its content? Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5nxde-rg8xbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.css

All good fixed it! :)
